# Selecting rows distinctively

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets assume my database table structure is something like

```
|   items    |   weight |
|============|==========|
|   item_1   |   50     |
|   item_2   |   90     |
|   item_2   |   45     |
|   item_2   |   60     |
|   item_3   |   40     |
```

In the select statement, I want to **show an item only for once with the highest weight** also ordered by height. So the result should be :

```
|   items    |   weight |
|============|==========|
|   item_2   |   90     |
|   item_1   |   50     |
|   item_3   |   40     |
```

I tried something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT items, weight FROM mytable ORDER BY weight DESC
```

but it didn't work because the results are actually distinct.

How can I make that selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to *group* your records by `items`:

```
SELECT   items, MAX(weight)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY items
ORDER BY MAX(weight) DESC
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0d88/1/0).

Answer (score 3):

```
select items, max(weight)
from mytable
group by items
```

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT items, MAX(weight) AS weight FROM mytable GROUP BY items ORDER BY weight DESC`

[Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)
The `SELECT MAX` syntax takes the largest result from a column, just using this would filter out one result with the highest weight, that's why you then use `GROUP BY` to separate the results in to matching results and the `MAX` is applied to all of them.

`GROUP BY` also has the handy by-product of ordering results (always `ASC` though), however in this case it would order the wrong column, so you have to add your own `ORDER BY`.

I'd use AS to create an alias for the max column to keep things tidy, otherwise you'll have to remember that the column will be called `MAX(weight)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want a group by:

```
select item, max(weight) as weight
from mytable
group by item
order by 2 desc
```